# What kind of doctor or physician do I need to consult for continuous coughing?

Tags: lungs, cough

I have a dry cough. It's persisting from last few months ( more than 3 months). There is no chest pain. Slight cold environment causes me urge to cough, irritation happens inside the chest. I have consulted a ENT(ears, nose, and throat) doctor, but he doesn't seem to guide me well. He asked me to take an antibiotic and cough syrup for all this time, but I don't see any relief. What kind of doctor or physician do I need to consult for my case?

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to health.SE! I modified your question because we can't really provide suggestions about dealing with the cough (that would be giving personal medical advice and we probably don't have enough information), so instead I reworded it to ask what kind of help you should look for. If you have any other questions, maybe try asking in a separate post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dry cough is most often non-inflammatory. If you had a flu or influenza prior to the beginning of the symptoms, then you might suffer from something post-viral. It is usually self-limiting. [(Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-viral_cough)

The fact that cold air provokes your symptoms might be indicative of [asthma](http://asthma.ca/teamasthma/asthma_coldair_manage_eng.pdf). As such, you may need to see a **pulmonary specialist**. Certainly he/she run some basic tests like a chest x-ray for a starter. **Spirometry** is also the routine test to be performed.

Comment: thanks for passing such an invaluable informations. I am new to this portal so sorry if the question was bit off. Thank you :)

Comment: seems like I had a allergic cough, I consulted with `pulmonary specialist` and he prescribed me `cetirizine` tablets to 30 days. I am already seeing some positive effects. :) thanks much for your help